# Find the number of moves to transform a set of numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> On the paper are three numbers: $1,\sqrt{2}$ and  $1 +\sqrt{2}$. In one move, you can choose two of the numbers, call them a
> and b, and replace these two with the numbers  $\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}$
> and $\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{2}}$. Is there a sequence of moves that
> transforms the three original numbers into $2, \sqrt{2}$
> and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ ? Hint: Consider the sum of the
> squares.

Let us consider the sum of squares, $a^2+b^2=(a+b)^2+2ab$ for the case $a=1$, $b=\sqrt{2}$:
$$1^2 + \sqrt{2}^2 =3$$
Consider $a=\sqrt{2}$, $b=1+\sqrt{2}$:
$$(\sqrt{2})^2 + (1+\sqrt{2})^2 = (\sqrt{2} + 1+\sqrt{2})^2 - 2\sqrt{2}(1+\sqrt{2})=(1+2\sqrt{2})^2 - 2\sqrt{2}(1+\sqrt{2})=5+\sqrt{2}$$
Then we consider the last option, $a=1$, $b=1+\sqrt{2}$:
$$(1^2+(1+\sqrt{2})^2)=(2+\sqrt{2})^2+2(1+\sqrt{2})=4+2\sqrt{2}$$

Now consider the sum of squares for the sought options, $a=2$, $b=\sqrt{2}$:

$$2^2+\sqrt{2}^2=6$$

and  $a=2$, $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$:
$$2^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}^2=4+\frac{1}{2}$$

and finally $a=\sqrt{2}$, $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$
$$\sqrt{2}^2+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}^2}=2+\frac{1}{2}$$

Can anyone see how the sum of squares relates to the number of moves one has to do to transform the original numbers into $2,\sqrt{2},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

It doesn't seem clear at all. Any ideas appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Consider a sum of squares of _all three numbers_ given, check how it behaves when you perform substitutions allowed and verify if it can reach the value resulting from the _desired final triple_. EDIT:  Stinking Bishop did a half of work for you already :)

Comment: As $\left(\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=\frac{a^2+2ab+b^2}{2}+\frac{a^2-2ab+b^2}{2}=a^2+b^2$, the operation on any two numbers there does not change the _total sum of squares of all three numbers_.

Comment: @StinkingBishop what a nickname!! Hilarious

Comment: [One of the best cheeses in the world!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_Bishop_(cheese))

Comment: ahahaha! Never heard of it.

Comment: you wrote $a^2+b^2= (a+b)^2 + 2ab$. It should be $-2ab$.

Comment: @user25406 both Stinking Bishop and I used +2ab .  Are we both wrong?

Comment: In the line below the general formula $a^2 +b^2=(a+b)^2 + 2ab$, you wrote $1+\sqrt{2}^2 =(1+\sqrt{2})^2 - 2\sqrt{2}$. So it's a bit confusing. Is-it a minus or a plus depending on using $a,b$ or $1,\sqrt{2}$

Comment: @user25406 Thanks, I see what you mean now.